# Ubuntu server 11.10 keeps going into power save mode

Tags: ubuntu, sleep

I have a clean Ubuntu server installation that keeps going into sleep mode if it receives no requests for a while. The only way to wake it up is to physically press the power button.  I can't imagine this being something that is the default setting for a server, but is it?  The server that it is installed on is rack-mounted i.e. not just a spare desktop.

Any ideas how to prevent it from going to sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Check you system settings -> Power Manager to see what it says.

If it is just default install, it should not go to sleep mode automatically, unless your bios is doing things such as power saving mode and wake on lan.

For server, though, you should consider to run an LTS version such as 10.04 or the coming 12.04 if you want the final beta and later upgrade to the real version.